# Knockout selectlist binding

Tags: javascript

I've done some tinkering about with Knockout in search for a better solution on how to bind select lists (dropdowns). I came up with a extender in combination with a binding.

Extender:

```
ko.extenders.selectList = function (target, params) {
                    var result = ko.computed({
                        read: target,
                        write: function (newValue) {
                            if (newValue) {
                                target(newValue);
                            } else {
                                target(undefined);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                //add some sub-observables
                result.options = $.map(params.options, function (v, k) { return { val: k, txt: v }; });
                result.caption = params.caption;

                function getInitialEnableValue(){
                    if(params.hasOwnProperty('enable')){
                        if($.isFunction(params.enable)){
                            return params.enable();
                        }
                        return params.enable;
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                var isEnabled = ko.observable(getInitialEnableValue());
                result.enable = ko.computed({
                    read: function(){
                        return isEnabled();
                    },
                    write: function(newValue){
                        if(!newValue) result(undefined);
                        isEnabled(newValue);
                    }
                });

                if(isEnabled() && result.options.length === 1){
                    result(result.options[0].val);
                }

                //return the new observable
                return result;
            };
```

Binding:

```
var selectListHTML = "<select data-bind=\"value: {0}, options: {0}.options, optionsCaption: {0}.caption, optionsText: 'txt', optionsValue: 'val', enable: {0}.enable\"></select>";
                    ko.bindingHandlers.selectList = {
                        init: function(element, vA, aBA,vm,bc){
                            $(element).html(selectListHTML.replace(/\{0\}/g,vA()));
                        }
                    };
```

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NV4gN/)

Are there any pitfalls I'm missing? Does this look like good code? Any comments welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: This is an old question, but still, it would be great it you could update your fiddle, right now it stopped working because it relies on http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a once over:

- Your indentation in `ko.extenders.selectList = function (target, params) {` should be 4 spaces to make it far more readable
- `write` could use a ternary approach:

  ```
  write: function (newValue) {
    target( newValue || undefined );
  }
  ```
- This code could use some more/better comment
- JSHint could find nothing wrong with it
- I am not too excited by seeing all those options as part of the HTML, it just feels wrong. None of the tools work for you in this case ( linting, beautifying, even colored syntax ). I guess that's more a reflection on knockout than on your code.